Updating CentOS Stream
I'm thinking to setup a server with CentOS stream, but I'm not quite understanding the upgrade model.
Once I install the OS I have a requirement that it's possible to continually update the OS including updating to major releases via command line.
Is this true for CentOS Stream? So for example if I build a server with CentOS Stream 9 I want to be able to go to version 10, 11 etc in an easy way via command line.
I believe OpenSuSE tumbleweed has this kind of model, you just keep on running zypper dist-upgrade and you're always up to date.
Is this true of CentOS stream too?

tumbleweed is really really different from CentOS and other major "stable" distros – it's a rolling distro, and probably really not what you want if you need something long-term stable.

Major upgrades of Stream can be done but they are not officially supported.
Strictly speaking, there is no officially supported in-place upgrade option for CentOS Stream. The only way that is 100% guaranteed to work is a reinstall.
That said, RHEL major version upgrades are officially supported by Red Hat using the Leapp system, and due to the inherent similarity of CentOS Stream with RHEL, you can use Leapp for Stream as well.
Leapp does not work entirely out of the box on Stream the way it does on RHEL, mainly because Stream does not have point (minor) releases while Leapp relies on point release numbers to figure out what adjustments need to be done to the system during an upgrade. Fortunately, patched Leapp is available, and does the job just fine. Most of those patches are already submitted for upstream inclusion, so with some luck this will start working with unmodified Leapp at a later stage.
The good thing about Leapp is that the entire upgrade is prepared ahead of time and all compatibility checks are done at that stage. So even if you have to perform the preupgrade in several iterations to iron out any wrinkles, this phase is entirely non-destructive. Only after everything is ready you reboot and apply the whole upgrade, which is fairly low risk at that point.
(FWIW, I have upgraded several servers from CentOS 7 via Stream 8 to Stream 9 without any trouble or unforeseen downtime.)


Is this true for CentOS Stream? So for example if I build a server with CentOS stream 9 I want to be able to go to version 10, 11 etc in an easy way via command line.

Not necessarily. It is difficult to say what the future will bring. Perhaps future releases of CentOS Stream will have a tool to upgrade to a major version without hassle, but you shouldn't be too hopeful on it.
I had a VPS with CentOS Stream 8 and I just did a full reinstall to Rocky Linux 9 because there was no way to easily migrate to CentOS Stream 9 or another RHEL-based distro. So, as I had to do a reinstall anyway, I chose Rocky Linux as is fully RHEL-compatible and more suited for a production environment than CentOS Stream, which is now upstream of RHEL.

@TooTea Agreed. I modified my post.
